# HttpGet works fine if called directly but issues a 400 response if called from Android Activity

Tags: java, android, https

The following code works fine to make an HTTPS call to my restful web service.  Building and executing from a simple Java application in Eclipse.

```
package test;

import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.security.KeyStore;
import java.security.cert.Certificate;
import java.security.cert.CertificateFactory;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.HttpVersion;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.conn.ClientConnectionManager;
import org.apache.http.conn.scheme.PlainSocketFactory;
import org.apache.http.conn.scheme.Scheme;
import org.apache.http.conn.scheme.SchemeRegistry;
import org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLSocketFactory;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.impl.conn.tsccm.ThreadSafeClientConnManager;
import org.apache.http.params.BasicHttpParams;
import org.apache.http.params.HttpParams;
import org.apache.http.params.HttpProtocolParams;
import org.apache.http.protocol.HTTP;

@SuppressWarnings("unused")
public class Test {
    private String filePath;

    private InputStream inputStream = null;

    private DefaultHttpClient hc = null;

    public Test(String filePath) {
        this.filePath = filePath;

        try {
            this.inputStream = new FileInputStream(filePath);

            if (this.inputStream != null) {
                Certificate myCert = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509")
                        .generateCertificate(this.inputStream);

                KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.getDefaultType());
                keyStore.load(null, null);
                keyStore.setCertificateEntry("myCert", myCert);

                SSLSocketFactory sf = new EasySSLSocketFactory(keyStore);
                sf.setHostnameVerifier(SSLSocketFactory.ALLOW_ALL_HOSTNAME_VERIFIER);

                HttpParams params = new BasicHttpParams();
                HttpProtocolParams.setVersion(params, HttpVersion.HTTP_1_1);
                HttpProtocolParams.setContentCharset(params, HTTP.UTF_8);
                HttpProtocolParams.setUseExpectContinue(params, true);

                SchemeRegistry registry = new SchemeRegistry();
                registry.register(new Scheme("http", PlainSocketFactory
                        .getSocketFactory(), 80));
                registry.register(new Scheme("https", sf, 443));

                ClientConnectionManager ccm = new ThreadSafeClientConnManager(
                        params, registry);

                hc = new DefaultHttpClient(ccm, params);

                // Prepare a request object
                String url = "https://service.cashyr.com:8443/PolarBear-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/get_deals_dist/33.7445273910949/-118.10924671590328/12/0/aaaa";
                HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet(url);

                // Execute the request
                HttpResponse response;

                InputStream instream = null;
                String data = null;

//                // setSeeMoreDealsButton(context, false);
                response = hc.execute(httpget);
                HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();

                instream = entity.getContent();
                if (instream != null) {
                    data = Utils.convertStreamToString(instream);
                    System.out.println(data);
                }
            }
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();

            hc = new DefaultHttpClient();
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();

            hc = new DefaultHttpClient();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Test("service.cashyr.com.crt");
    }
}
```

Now I created another android application in Eclipse (not activity is just a simple activity with a simple button and the listener in the code is connected to that button.  Anyway I run this activity and in the on click listener that will run an AsyncTask to run the afformentioned HTTPS call verbatim, it returns a 400 response.  Why is this?  I am totally confused as I am sure I am following all the procedures for doing HTTPS.  Well apparently not totally sure since it doesn't work.  But it works with the straight Java application.  Why is this?  Please help!!!!

Android activity is as follows:

```
package com.example.testandroidapp;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.security.KeyStore;
import java.security.cert.Certificate;
import java.security.cert.CertificateFactory;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.HttpVersion;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.conn.ClientConnectionManager;
import org.apache.http.conn.scheme.PlainSocketFactory;
import org.apache.http.conn.scheme.Scheme;
import org.apache.http.conn.scheme.SchemeRegistry;
import org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLSocketFactory;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.impl.conn.tsccm.ThreadSafeClientConnManager;
import org.apache.http.params.BasicHttpParams;
import org.apache.http.params.HttpParams;
import org.apache.http.params.HttpProtocolParams;
import org.apache.http.protocol.HTTP;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    Button button1;

    private class ConnectionTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String> {
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            Log.d("MY_LOG", "Finished loading end point");
        }

        protected String doInBackground(String... arg) {
            String url = arg[0];

            Log.d("MY_LOG", "Started loading end point");

            DefaultHttpClient hc = null;
            String data = null;

            try {
                InputStream inputStream = MainActivity.class
                        .getResourceAsStream("service.cashyr.com.crt");

                if (inputStream != null) {
                    Log.d("MY_LOG", "Loaded certificate file successfully");

                    Certificate myCert = CertificateFactory.getInstance(
                            "X.509").generateCertificate(inputStream);

//                  Log.d("MY_LOG", "Certificate contents:" + myCert.toString());
                    Log.d("MY_LOG", "Certificate object loaded");

                    KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore
                            .getDefaultType());
                    Log.d("MY_LOG", "Obtained keystore");
                    keyStore.load(null, null);
                    Log.d("MY_LOG", "keystore loaded");
                    keyStore.setCertificateEntry("myCert", myCert);
                    Log.d("MY_LOG", "set certificate entry");

                    SSLSocketFactory sf = new EasySSLSocketFactory(keyStore);
                    Log.d("MY_LOG", "created SSL socket factory");
                    sf.setHostnameVerifier(SSLSocketFactory.ALLOW_ALL_HOSTNAME_VERIFIER);
                    Log.d("MY_LOG", "set host name verifier");

                    HttpParams params = new BasicHttpParams();
                    HttpProtocolParams.setVersion(params,
                            HttpVersion.HTTP_1_1);
                    HttpProtocolParams
                            .setContentCharset(params, HTTP.UTF_8);
                    Log.d("MY_LOG", "set up HTTP params");

                    SchemeRegistry registry = new SchemeRegistry();
                    registry.register(new Scheme("http", PlainSocketFactory
                            .getSocketFactory(), 80));
                    registry.register(new Scheme("https", sf, 8443));
                    Log.d("MY_LOG", "set up sche registry");

                    ClientConnectionManager ccm = new ThreadSafeClientConnManager(
                            params, registry);
                    Log.d("MY_LOG", "created client connection manager object");

                    hc = new DefaultHttpClient(ccm, params);
                    Log.d("MY_LOG", "create default http client object for sending http request");

                    // Prepare a request object
                    HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet(url);

                    // Execute the request
                    HttpResponse response;

                    InputStream instream = null;

                    // // setSeeMoreDealsButton(context, false);
                    response = hc.execute(httpget);
                    Log.d("MY_LOG", "Sent https (SSL) get request.");

                    HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();

                    instream = entity.getContent();
                    if (instream != null) {
                        data = Utils.convertStreamToString(instream);
                        Log.d("MY_LOG", "HTTPS response:  \n" + data);
                    }
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();

                hc = new DefaultHttpClient();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();

                hc = new DefaultHttpClient();
            }

            return data;
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        button1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                String url = "https://service.cashyr.com:8443/PolarBear-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/get_deals_dist/33.7445273910949/-118.10924671590328/12/0/aaaa";
                new ConnectionTask().execute(url);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }
}
```

Thanks,
Jeff

P.S.  Logcat is here:

```
08-01 09:24:51.003: D/memalloc(17677): ion: Unmapping buffer  base:0x5bbed000 size:1536000
08-01 09:24:51.003: D/memalloc(17677): ion: Unmapping buffer  base:0x5c070000 size:1536000
08-01 09:24:51.003: D/memalloc(17677): ion: Unmapping buffer  base:0x5c2eb000 size:1536000
08-01 09:24:55.848: I/System.out(18055): Debugger has connected
08-01 09:24:55.848: I/System.out(18055): waiting for debugger to settle...
08-01 09:24:56.048: I/System.out(18055): waiting for debugger to settle...
08-01 09:24:56.258: I/System.out(18055): waiting for debugger to settle...
08-01 09:24:56.448: I/System.out(18055): waiting for debugger to settle...
08-01 09:24:56.649: I/System.out(18055): waiting for debugger to settle...
08-01 09:24:56.859: I/System.out(18055): waiting for debugger to settle...
08-01 09:24:57.049: I/System.out(18055): waiting for debugger to settle...
08-01 09:24:57.259: I/System.out(18055): waiting for debugger to settle...
08-01 09:24:57.449: I/System.out(18055): waiting for debugger to settle...
08-01 09:24:57.650: I/System.out(18055): waiting for debugger to settle...
08-01 09:24:57.850: I/System.out(18055): waiting for debugger to settle...
08-01 09:24:58.060: I/System.out(18055): debugger has settled (1401)
08-01 09:24:58.340: I/Adreno200-EGLSUB(18055): <ConfigWindowMatch:2218>: Format RGBA_8888.
08-01 09:24:58.350: D/memalloc(18055): ion: Mapped buffer base:0x5bced000 size:1536000 offset:0 fd:58
08-01 09:24:58.350: E/(18055): Can't open file for reading
08-01 09:24:58.350: E/(18055): Can't open file for reading
08-01 09:24:58.450: D/memalloc(18055): ion: Mapped buffer base:0x5c170000 size:1536000 offset:0 fd:62
08-01 09:25:04.146: D/memalloc(18055): ion: Mapped buffer base:0x5c2eb000 size:1536000 offset:0 fd:65
08-01 09:25:04.276: D/MY_LOG(18055): Started loading end point
08-01 09:25:04.426: D/MY_LOG(18055): Loaded certificate file successfully
08-01 09:25:04.847: D/MY_LOG(18055): Certificate object loaded
08-01 09:25:04.847: D/MY_LOG(18055): Obtained keystore
08-01 09:25:04.847: D/MY_LOG(18055): keystore loaded
08-01 09:25:04.847: D/MY_LOG(18055): set certificate entry
08-01 09:25:04.857: D/MY_LOG(18055): created SSL socket factory
08-01 09:25:04.857: D/MY_LOG(18055): set host name verifier
08-01 09:25:04.857: D/MY_LOG(18055): set up HTTP params
08-01 09:25:04.867: D/MY_LOG(18055): set up sche registry
08-01 09:25:04.877: D/MY_LOG(18055): created client connection manager object
08-01 09:25:04.887: D/MY_LOG(18055): create default http client object for sending http request
08-01 09:25:07.469: D/MY_LOG(18055): Sent https (SSL) get request.
08-01 09:25:07.479: D/MY_LOG(18055): HTTPS response:  
08-01 09:25:07.479: D/MY_LOG(18055): <?xml version='1.0'?>
08-01 09:25:07.479: D/MY_LOG(18055): <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC '-//WAPFORUM//DTD XHTML Mobile 1.0//EN'
08-01 09:25:07.479: D/MY_LOG(18055): 'http://www.wapforum.org/DTD/xhtml-mobile10.dtd'>
08-01 09:25:07.479: D/MY_LOG(18055): <html xmlns='http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml'>
08-01 09:25:07.479: D/MY_LOG(18055): <head>
08-01 09:25:07.479: D/MY_LOG(18055): <title>The request failed</title>
08-01 09:25:07.479: D/MY_LOG(18055): </head>
08-01 09:25:07.479: D/MY_LOG(18055): <body>
08-01 09:25:07.479: D/MY_LOG(18055): <p><big>The request is not understood.</big></p>
08-01 09:25:07.479: D/MY_LOG(18055): <p>
08-01 09:25:07.479: D/MY_LOG(18055): <i>Technical description:</i><br/>400 Bad Request - Check your spelling for the requested URL</p>
08-01 09:25:07.479: D/MY_LOG(18055): </body>
08-01 09:25:07.479: D/MY_LOG(18055): </html>
08-01 09:25:07.479: D/MY_LOG(18055): Finished loading end point
```

Comment: can you share yout logcat?

Comment: Just added plus I modified the code above to show my log statements.  The log cat was unremarkable until I added a few logging lines.

Comment: I have no idea why I get the following:

 08-01 09:24:58.350: E/(18055): Can't open file for reading
 08-01 09:24:58.350: E/(18055): Can't open file for reading

I seem to see this in every android application that I write from bare bones to complex.  I accepted that it must be some bug in the SDK.

Comment: Okay apparently it issues the 400 error if I switch my phone to 4g but if I turn on wireless it works.  Why is this?  I cannot have the users switch to wireless whenever they want to use the product!!  When I am on 4g or 3g for that matter it should just be an IP address the same as any other with direct net access.  I am lost and have no idea how to resolve this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK Folks check this out Keep it very simple - it is not the script that is bad, No sir..
Your Web.Config may have a HttP conflict that 400 error is asking to load a webpage that is not responding. So you must check a few minor details minor bcs you know the script is good so now you have to check your setting and how the computer and browser responds...

To Resolve try this 
First Clear your DNS Cache and delete cookies
1. Reset your web browser then go to script replace website.com with actual web url.
2. for service, replace webHttpBinding with basicHttpBinding 
3. Make sure your header lines are not long

remember keep it simple 
For further assistance email me Frankieperez@yahoo.com